# The Homeworld base

Tags: smash-up

I have this question about the Homeworld base ability. The text says: After each time a minion is played here, its owner may play an extra minion of power 2 or less". I was just wondering if I understood it correctly. So, lets say I couple Killer Plants with Robots and on my turn I play **Blossom** (lets me play 3 Ms with the same name) = 4 minions (e.g. **Nukebot** + 3 **hoverbots** - each of the 3 getting me an additional minion to play on another base) on this base, so I get to play 4 extra minions - maybe 4 **Zapbots**; now I´m up to 8 extra minions, which I may play on other bases and, having **Microbots** and **Sprouts** (none exceeding the power 2 limit), I may as well get those 15VPs in just one turn. Sure, it is a highly unlikely scenario, but is there anything I missed or is it an improbable, yet possible, scenario, given that I may have more than 10 Ms in my hand if an opponent returned them to me - Crop Circles?

Comment: Please provide the text of the cards you discuss rather than making us look them up.

Comment: Sorry for that, I´ll do next time.

Answer (score 1):

What's your question? Are you asking for the odds of having the following?

- Homeworld in play
- 1 Blossom in your hand
- 1 Nukebot in your hand
- 3 Hoverbots in your hand
- 4 Zapbots in your hand
- 4 other minions of power ≤2 in your hand
- 3 minions on the top of your deck

Considering that's three more cards in your hand than than the maximum hand size, someone would have had to made you draw three cards since your last turn ended.

I'd say the odds of that are zero, zilch, nada, nul.

---

Like you said, it's technically possible for something like Crop Circle to give you the extra cards you need, at which point the following extra restrictions are added to the list:

- You have at least three of the minions that need to be in your hand on a base.
- A player is using Aliens.
- A player has Crop Circles in his hand.
- A player uses Crop Circles on that base.

Calculating the exact odds is pointless (well, impossible really), but they are infinitesimal.

---

And then there's the claim that this could give you 15 VP. Even if you manage to pull of your combo, this is far from a sure thing.

A Nukebot and three Hoverbots gives 17 points, which is 6 shy of breaking The Homeworld. Let's say three of the 8 unnamed minions are Microbot Alpha and two Microbot Fixers. Homeworld then sits at 22, so you still have to waste one of your 8 unassigned minions on Homeworld.

That leaves you Microbot Alpha (18), two Microbot Fixers (3), four other minions (at +2 of base). That gives you 36-45 power to get 11 points.

Well, it's possible, but it introduces a slew of new conditions:

- You have Microbot Alpha in your hand or as one of the top three cards of your deck.
- You have two Microbot Fixer in your hand or as one of the top three cards of your deck.
- The bases in play other than The Homeworld must be able to pay out 11 VP.

  - There must be at least three bases in addition to The Homeworld. (I only saw 3 base combinations out of 117,600 that permit a two-player win.)

    - There must be at least three players.
- Your and your opponents must have enough minions on the bases to score four bases.

  - Don't forget that he just used Crop Circle on you.
- You must have the highest scoring place in at least two of the bases other than The Homeworld.

Not gonna happen.

---

Buy lottery tickets. The odds are far better, and so are the rewards. With your winnings, you could build machines to play Smash Up until they pull off the combo. But you'll surely die first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. My primary concern was to ensure I got the Homeworld text right, so I guess I did. 
I totally agree with you that the chance is too small to hope for. But, just to make sure I didn´t miss a thing about the rules of the individual cards, let me show you my "winning strategy" (at least one): I play Nukebot + 3 Hoverbots (due to Bloosom) on Homeworld, get to play Venus Man Trap + 2 Weed Eaters on Evans City Cemetery (due to Hoverbots), 2 Zapbots on Homeworld and the rest (2 Sprouts, 2 M. Fixers, M. Alpha, M. Archive on Rhodes Plaza Mall = 15VP (just 3 bases, alone)

Comment: Mind you that Microbot Alpha makes all my minions on all bases Microbots and gives all of them (apart from itself) +1 power, and 2 Microbot Fixers each giving all my minions +1 power so that all my minions get additional +3 power apart from Microbot Alpha with additional +2 power.
Again not intending to use such a combo but wondering if my reasoning is valid or not

Comment: @Martin, your reasoning is entirely valid. The Robots are capable of some truly amazing turns. The main drawback is that once you've played a bunch of cards in a row, your hand is empty (or nearly so). (And if that turn didn't make you win, everyone will target you.) And yes, your Microbot Alpha + Microbot Fixers don't actually apply their +power to other minions until they're in play, so you can still play your less-than-2-power minions even if they're going to get some bonuses immediately after play.

Comment: You got Microbot Alpha wrong. MA gives *itself* +1 for each other Microbot you have. Basically, its power is the number of minions you have.

Comment: @ikegami, thanks, now that I checked the wording I see I´ve been playing it wrong. Appreciate it. So the number of points is actually the same, just their distribution is different.

Comment: So just for kicks, here´s my updated "winning combo", though it´s hardly anything more than a theory, really:
I start off with Blossom (3 extra Ms with the same name - 3 Hoverbots), Homeworld - Nukebot + 2 Hoverbots + Warbot (drawn), Rhodes Plaza Mall - Hoverbot + Warbot (drawn) + 2 M Fixers + 2 Zapbots, Evans City Cemetery - Venus Man Trap (drawn) + M Alpha = 15 VPs, all alone with 10 cards + 3 drawn...